Where do .resx (resource) files live in a dotnet application when one is using areas?
I'm working on a dotnet application that is using localization. I'm stuck on understanding where my .resx files are supposed to live.
The current file structure looks like this:
 - Root
    - Views
       - Home
           - Home.cshtml
    - Resources
       - Views.Home.Home.es.resx

That seems to work just fine.
However, I'm trying to add a resource file for my view that is in an Area:
 - Root
    - Areas
       - Myarea
          - Views
              - Home
                 - Home.cshtml
    - Views
       - Home
           - Home.cshtml
    - Resources
       - Views.Home.Home.es.resx

And this is where I'm stuck. I can't figure out a) where my resx file should be placed in the above structure and b) how it should be named.
It appears resx files in dotnet are just kind of 'magic'...as long as you name them correctly and put them in the right place, the app finds them. However, I can't find any definitive information on to use them within an Area.
Based on various suggestions online I've tried:

putting my resx file in the same directory as my view
making a Resources directory within my area and placing it there
replicating the file directory hierarchy that is in my area inside of the root Resources directory and placing my file there.
doing all of the above with various file names

Is there a proper/specific answer to "where do localization resource files live so that an Area in a dotnet application finds them?"

From the Resource file naming,

Resources are named for the full type name of their class minus the assembly name.

A resource for the class LocalizationWebsite.Web.Controllers.HomeController would be named Controllers.HomeController.fr.resx.

Assuming we set the ResourcesPath to "Resources", the resource file associated with the Views/Home/About.cshtml view could be either of the following:

Resources/Views/Home/About.fr.resx

Resources/Views.Home.About.fr.resx




Through checking the namespace for the razor page/controller file in the "Myarea" area, the namespace should be:
<Your Web application assembly name>.Areas.Myarea.Controllers

Hence, the resource file name for the area should be in this format:

For controller: Areas.<Area Name>.Controllers.<Controller name>.<Action name>.<locale>.resx

For views: Areas.<Area Name>.Views.<View directory>.<View name>.<locale>.resx


You should name the file as: Areas.Myarea.Views.Home.Home.es.resx
The directories and files of your web application is as below:
 - Root
    - Areas
       - Myarea
          - Views
              - Home
                 - Home.cshtml
    - Views
       - Home
           - Home.cshtml
    - Resources
       - Views.Home.Home.es.resx
       - Areas.Myarea.Views.Home.Home.es.resx

